# mysql ошибка запроса

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT source_id FROM tables INNER JOIN episodes ON episodes.anime_id=anime.name INNER JOIN episodes On source_id=episodes.anime_id
```

ругается на повторное episodes как переформатировать запрос с AS пытался ничего благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: `join episodes e1 on e1.anime_id=anume.name join episodes e2 on e2. ...` p.s. сравнение id с name выглядит очень странно

Comment: я не сравниваю а делаю подмену значения

Comment: вообще сравниваете, знак `=` - это сравнение `episodes.anime_id=anime.name` и данное условие говорит "найди в таблице anime такие строки у которых имя равно id из таблицы episodes"

Comment: у меня есть 3 таблицы во 2  таблице у меня поле anime_id я делаю подменус с таблицей anime колонкой name по id потом я беру  готовое поле с подменой и привязываю с таблицей source_id название аниме по id если есть возможность помогите с запросом

Comment: кстати зачем нужна вторая episodes из запроса пока не ясно. хотя для чего первая то же не совсем ясно, никаких значений из этих таблиц вы в итоге не выводите. выводиться только source_id, который как я понял находится в первой таблице. т.е. фактически сейчас эти 2 join используются либо что бы не допустить вывода source_id для которых ненайдется записей в episodes, либо для размножения записей, т.е. вывода одного и того же source_id столько раз, сколько найдется записей в episodes

Comment: мне надо чтоб source_id выдавал не цифровой код ида серии а название аниме поэтому я подменяю сначала в таблице 2 колонку anime_id на колонку 1 таблицы name потом полученый anime_id связываю по id с source_id проблема в том что я немогу нормально это все прописать

Comment: SELECT anime.name FROM tables INNER JOIN anime ON tables.source_id = anime.id WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 40 DAY) <= data

Comment: код который похожие но он делает это именно по id_anime а мне надо вытягивать через source_id 3 таблицы

Comment: я очень плохо знай mysql поэтому такие вопросы

Comment: ну в этом помочь вам никто не сможет не видя структуры таблиц и точного объяснения что на основе чего надо получить. В идеале приводят структуру таблиц в виде create table, образец содержимого и результат, который на основе этого содержимого получается. И все это в текстовом виде

Comment: я понимаю спасибо за ответ